# Avoid heap allocation when inserting into sorted vector<unique_ptr<pair<>>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some data stored in:
`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key, Data>>>` where `Data` is some large sized object, and `Key` uniquely identifies `Data`. We can assume there are no duplicates on `Key` and this vector is sorted ascending based on `Key`.

I have implemented `insert` in following way (following standard containers)

```
bool compare(const std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key,Data>>& elem,
             const std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key,Data>>& input)
{
  return elem->first < input->first;
}

typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key, Data>>> DataStore;

std::pair<DataStore::iterator, bool>
insert(DataStore& vec, const Key& k, const Data& d)
{
  using namespace std::placeholders; // for using bind

  // vvv-- This heap allocation seems unnecessary when element already exists.
  // seems mainly needed for lower_bound to work
  std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key,Data>> valPtr(new std::pair<Key,Data>(k,d));

  auto location = std::lower_bound(std::begin(vec),
                                   std::end(vec), valPtr,
                                   std::bind(&compare, _1, _2));
  // exists, return element location 
  if(location != vec.end() && (*location)->first == k) {
    return std::make_pair(location, false);
  }

  // non-existing element, add it to the right location
  auto addedLocation = vec.emplace(location, std::move(valPtr));
  return std::make_pair(addedLocation, true);
}
```

Could someone suggest ways to avoid allocation in `insert` in the comment location above?

I would prefer not to write my own implementation of lower_bound/binary_search.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::find` instead? It doesn't abort early, but at least you can give it a simple predicate for comparison.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::map`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, from what I understand, `std::find` will do linear search. I want to take advantage of sorted vector.

Comment: I can't see why you're not using std::map. BTW, the type of value used to compare need not be same as value type of iterator. So the second argument to the comparator and the third to the search function can be of key type.

Comment: @Red.Wave That "BTW" is an answer. You can post it as such (note that there are already 2 answers mentioning that, though, but if you think yours would contribute, you can still answer)

Comment: they were not visible on android app. Now I see all on pc browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) doesn't require any relationship between the type `T` of the object that we are searching for and the type of the elements, other than the fact that we have to be able to compare them with `cmp(element, value)`<sup>1</sup>. We can make use of that fact:

```
std::pair<DataStore::iterator, bool>
insert(DataStore& vec, const Key& k, const Data& d)
{
  // Note: since you are using C++11, you can use lambdas rather than `std::bind`.
  // This simplifies your code and makes it easier for the compiler to optimize
  auto location = std::lower_bound(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), k,
    [](const std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key,Data>>& elem, const Key& key) {
      return elem->first < key;
    });

  // exists, return element location 
  if(location != vec.end() && (*location)->first == k) {
    return std::make_pair(location, false);
  }

  // non-existing element, add it to the right location
  auto addedLocation = vec.emplace(location, new std::pair<Key,Data>(k,d));
  return std::make_pair(addedLocation, true);
}
```

<sup>1: A lot of the standard algorithms do this. They are designed to be as general as possible, so they place as few requirements on the types passed in as is reasonable.</sup>

Comment: Preferred this solution as it doesn't require creating pair with heavy `Data` in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and similar functions don't actually require the functor to take two arguments of the same type.

`lower_bound` expects a functor such that the dereferenced iterator can be used as the first argument and the object to search for can be used as the second argument:

```
auto location = std::lower_bound(
    v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::make_pair(k,d),
    [](const std::unique_ptr<std::pair<Key, Data>>& ptr,
       const std::pair<Key, Data>& val)
    { return ptr->first < val.first; } );
```